# R gtsummary Overall Column Moved After Merge

Tags: r, summary, gtsummary, tbl

In the past, when I've created a summary table with an overall column and merged it, the column remains on the left. However, recently, after merging and modifying the spanning header, the overall column is not on the left.

Here is an example:

```
library(gtsummary)

t1 <- trial %>% select(trt, age) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt) %>% 
  add_overall(col_label = "**Overall**") %>% 
  modify_header(stat_by = "**{level}**") 

t2 <- trial %>% select(grade, age) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = grade) %>% 
  modify_header(stat_by = "**{level}**") 

tbl_merge(
    tbls = list(t1, t2),
    tab_spanner = c("**Treatment**", "**Tumor Grade**")
  ) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(stat_0_1 ~ NA) %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA)
```

Looking at the first table prior to merging (t1), the overall column is on the left:
[image: t1]

Once the merge occurs, the overall column has moved:
[image: tbl_merge]

I was using the same code as was suggested in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623256/r-gtsummary-row-with-categorical-variable-totals). Has something changed with the recent package update, is there something in my code that may be the culprit, or is there a workaround to get the overall column on the left?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: FYI I can a look at this later this afternoon. In the meantime, can you please up your example to be minimal... including the fewest lines of code to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have edited the code.

Comment: Thank you so much posting about this behavior. It's due to a bug introduced in the latest version, and has been corrected. Install the dev version with `remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary")`

Comment: Thanks fornlooking at this. Much appreciated.